# Is there a standard-compliant way to assign segments of a Fortran parameter array on multiple lines?

Tags: fortran

I have a parameter-array which spans a few thousands of lines in the source code, each line of which is already around 132 characters long. An obvious way to assign this array in a standard-compliant way is to remove the `parameter` attribute and assign segments of the array in chunks of 255 line continuations. But, this is bad, since the array is indeed constant not a variable. Is there a way to achieve this without removing the `parameter` attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can built up a named-constant from other named-constants.

```
program foo
   integer, parameter :: a(5)  = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
   integer, parameter :: b(10) = [a, a]
   print '(5(I0,1X))', a
   print '(10(I0,1X))', b
end program foo
```

I suspect that this has already been asked and answered.

Another option is to read the data into a `PROTECTED` entity.

```
module mydata

  implicit none

  private

  integer, protected, allocatable :: a(:)
  public a, init_a

  contains

  subroutine init_a
     integer fd, n
     open(newunit=fd,file='a.dat',status='old',access='stream')
     read(fd) n
     allocate(a(n))
     read(fd) a
     close(fd)
  end subroutine init_a

end module mydata

program foo
  use mydata
  call init_a
  print '(5(I0,1X))', a(1:5)
end program foo
```

Comment: This worked. But I suspect this approach could lead to code bloat for effectively creating a redundant duplicate of the constant arrays, in extreme cases of very large arrays.

Comment: btw, see the discussion here (the next standard will likely remove all line-continuation and max-line-length limits): https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-visual-fortran-compiler-for-windows/topic/816866#comment-1944489

Comment: The next standard is 5 years away.  Are you going to wait that long?  If you have a need for a several thousand line long named constant, then the above will get it for you.  Wasted space?  Probably.  I would read the data in from a file if it is that big.